# Prolog looping due to interdependency

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

Have to write some prolog rules to represent the geometrical properties about isosceles triangle.

First rule is to say

```
angleEqual(angle(A,B,C),angle(A,C,B)):- 
    triangle(A,B,C), 
    lineEqual(line(A,B),line(A,C)).
```

Second rule says

```
lineEqual(line(A,B),line(A,C)):- 
    triangle(A,B,C), 
    angleEqual(angle(A,B,C),angle(A,C,B)).
```

But the two rules together will cause a interdependency and prolog is looping forever if given facts such as

```
triangle(a,b,c).
lineEqual(line(a,b),line(a,c)).
```

and query about

```
?- angleEqual(A,B).
```

Any idea? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could remove 'naming redundancy', given you have *facts* that states the geometrical properties of your entities.

```
angleEqual(angle(A,B,C),angle(A,C,B)):-
    triangle(A,B,C),
    equal(line(A,B),line(A,C)).

lineEqual(line(A,B),line(A,C)):-
    triangle(A,B,C),
    equal(angle(A,B,C),angle(A,C,B)).

triangle(a,b,c).
equal(line(a,b),line(a,c)).
```

with that your query will get an answer

```
?- angleEqual(A,B).
A = angle(a, b, c),
B = angle(a, c, b).
```

I must say I a bit sceptical about the representation, I would try to base the description on *points* and *distance measures* instead. Some Prolog (for instance, SWI-Prolog) come equipped with high precision numeric evaluation and rational arithmetic. But surely the description would be more difficult than your...

Comment: If you use equal/2 then you have to have the rules:equal(A,B):- lineEqual(A,B);angleEqual(A,B) which will also create an infinity loop. I do not think it is a naming dependency since the angleEqual/2 and lineEqual/2 are also derived from other rules, I am only supplying it as fact for illustration purpose. But I would be grateful if you could give a little hints on your idea you suggested. Thanks very much.